# Comparing present day and previous week same day sales in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am new to Quicksight and I have built a dashboard that shows current day sales on hour basis. I select the day based on a control panel.
Now I want to build for previous week too, for example if I select 07/04 in control panel in dashboard with line chart shows on hourly basis total sales but I also want another line in the same dashboard previous week (07/28) sales on hourly basis.

Can anyone how please guid how to do the second part of showing even the previous week.